# iframe src attribute jquery execution twice

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, iframe

I'm parsing src of an iframe through jquery. As soon as I trigger an event, PDF is displayed in the iframe and gain it disappears and loading again slowly. What would be the cause for it?

```
<script>
function viewpdf(){ 
$('iframe').attr('src', '<?php echo $pdf;?>');
;}
viewpdf();
</script>
   <button onclick="viewpdf();">click</button>
   <iframe id="iframe"  style="width:100%;height:92.5%;"></iframe>
```

When the page loads `viewpdf()` function will execute and when I click button again pdf should be loaded into the iframe but it displays pdf suddenly and disappers and again pdf is loading. And sometimes even pdf exists in the folder am getting the error like below
[image]

Comment: If PDF is already loaded on page load then how it can load again on the button click? What do you expect?

Comment: Iframe is in the div element. Close button will be there. If I click close button div with iframe display will be changed to none. So after that If I click PDF button it should again display the PDF. So, After I closed iframe then again when I click button, PDF quickly appears then disappears and loading again.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think to achieve what you said in the comment, your code is not a good way. Do it like this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('iframe').attr('src', '<?php echo $pdf;?>');


    $("#close").click(function(){
    $("iframe").hide();
    });


    $("#open").click(function(){
    $("iframe").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

You should not load the PDF again and again if you are not changing the `src`.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, but I need to  switch between two src of an iframe. How to do it in this way? And also, my last query in my post is, even pdf exists in the folder sometimes it displays like `Failed to load PDF document` in an iframe. I couldn't to predict when will it happen?how to solve it? And what would be the reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
function viewpdf(){ 
$('#iframe').attr("src", "http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf");
}

         <button onClick="viewpdf()">click</button>
   <iframe id="iframe"  style="width:100%;height:92.5%;"></iframe>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can I know what's the difference between my code and yours?